# How to fetch specific hashtag post (updated)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I am trying to fetch specific post by users based on what category that user selects.

For example I have a collection view with multiple categories such as "Cold Shoulder, Bike Shorts, Gold"

If a user uses a hashtag #bikeshorts on a post, that post will also be featured in the category called Bike Shorts.

How can I fetch the photos that contain the hashtag #bikeshorts ?

Here is my database structure via Firebase (There are 2 post in total that use the hashtag "bike shorts" )

[image]

Here is the code I am trying now but no success

```swift
 func fetchPosts() {
    if trendName == "Bike Shorts" {
            print("Fetching posts with the hashtag bikeshorts")

            let query = HASHTAG_POST_REF.queryEqual(toValue: "bikeshorts")
            query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                  let postId = snapshot.key
                Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                    self.posts.append(post)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
            }

           }

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I was able to get the post for bike shorts to fetch! 
This is the code I used

```swift
func fetchPosts() {
    if trendName == "Bike Shorts" {
            print("Fetching posts with the hashtag bikeshorts")

         HASHTAG_POST_REF.child("bikeshorts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

                let postId = snapshot.key
                Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                    self.posts.append(post)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })


           }

    }


    }
```